# Return expensive function call if not None

Tags: python

I have an expensive function `bt`. I need to return the value of `bt(x, y, carries, n)` only if it is not `None` (or `== False`, whatever). I am currently doing it like this:

```
foo = bt(x, y, carries, n)
if foo:
    return foo
```

This is silly. On the other hand, I don't want to needlessly call `bt` twice since it's very expensive. How can I express this elegantly without hurting performance?
(I'm using python 2.7.6, but am interested in answers for python 3 as well).

Comment: Why do you think it's silly?

Comment: If there's no better way to do it, it's not silly. But I think there is.

Comment: It depends on what you want to return otherwise. BTW, your current code will skip not only `None` but any `False`-like value.

Comment: It's either an integer or None, so that doesn't matter.

Comment: In your code fragment you don't call the `bt` function twice.

Comment: What if the function returns `0`?

Comment: I know, but the elegant way to do it would be `if bt(...): \n return bt(...)`

Comment: "But I think there is." what makes you think that?  You want to return a value only sometimes.  That's exactly what your code snippet does.  Your suggested alternative is *not* more elegant.  In addition to being wasteful, it violates DRY.

Comment: @RenéG code duplicates are never elegant, so it wouldn't. Python does not optimize anything for you.

Comment: Well, if I used `if bt(...): \n return bt(...)`, the compiler would propogate the constant by making a temporary variable (I think?). I thought maybe there's a way to do the same in python.

Comment: At least, in a functional language it would! `bt` doesn't have side effects. But I guess not C, it wouldn't know about the side effects.

Comment: "the compiler would propogate the constant" what?

Comment: @RenéG: if the function is pure you could memoize it (e.g. with lru_cache), so that the computation would only be done once.  But I don't see the point just to avoid `if foo: return foo`.

Comment: @DSM That's interesting! I didn't know the standard lib had memoization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is more to do when `bt` returns `None` (Otherwise there is an implicit `None` returned anyway)

Apart from using a meaningful name for the return value - what you already have is the preferred way to do it

```
bt_retval = bt(x, y, carries, n)
if bt_retval is not None:
    return bt_retval
del bt_retval # optional (it really isn't wasting much memory)
# otherwise carry on
```